# How do I call an Angular 2 pipe with multiple arguments?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-pipe

I know I can call a pipe like this:

```
{{ myData | date:'fullDate' }}
```

Here the date pipe takes only one argument.
What is the syntax to call a pipe with more parameters, from component's template HTML and directly in code?

Answer (score 644, accepted):

In your component's template you can use multiple arguments by separating them with colons:

```
{{ myData | myPipe: 'arg1':'arg2':'arg3'... }}
```

From your code it will look like this:

```
new MyPipe().transform(myData, arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

And in your transform function inside your pipe you can use the arguments like this:

```
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform { 
    // specify every argument individually   
    transform(value: any, arg1: any, arg2: any, arg3: any): any { }
    // or use a rest parameter
    transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any { }
}
```

**Beta 16 and before (2016-04-26)**

Pipes take an array that contains all arguments, so you need to call them like this:

```
new MyPipe().transform(myData, [arg1, arg2, arg3...])
```

And your transform function will look like this:

```
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {    
    transform(value:any, args:any[]):any {
        var arg1 = args[0];
        var arg2 = args[1];
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This design is silly. I need to check document every time I come across this issue

Comment: What would the template bit look like if `arg1` and `arg2` where both optional and you only wanted to pass in `arg2`?

Comment: if you pass `undefined` as the first argument it will get its default value.

Comment: nowadays instead of ``transform(value:any, arg1:any, arg2:any, arg3:any)`` using the rest operator feels better I think: ``transform(value:any, ...args:any[])``

Comment: why transform(...args) causes an error, but transform(value, ...args) not?

Comment: @eran-shabi I have async transform pipe accepting array parameter (it's data field). The issue is I am spammed with multiple calls of async instead of one. I don't know why: `<td> {{ getFamilyIds(data.listFamilies) | abxDictionaryItemsAsync : DICT_TYPE | async }}</td> `, pipe transform looks like that: `transform<T>(value: T[], dicType: DictionaryType): Observable<string>`

Comment: Is it documented at all? I can't find it.

Answer (score 71):

You're missing the actual pipe.

```
{{ myData | date:'fullDate' }}
```

Multiple parameters can be separated by a colon (:).

```
{{ myData | myPipe:'arg1':'arg2':'arg3' }}
```

Also you can chain pipes, like so:

```
{{ myData | date:'fullDate' | myPipe:'arg1':'arg2':'arg3' }}
```

Answer (score 35):

Since beta.16 the parameters are not passed as array to the `transform()` method anymore but instead as individual parameters:

```
{{ myData | date:'fullDate':'arg1':'arg2' }}


export class DatePipe implements PipeTransform {    
  transform(value:any, arg1:any, arg2:any):any {
        ...
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta16-2016-04-26

> pipes now take a variable number of arguments, and not an array that contains all arguments.

Comment: What would the template bit look like if `arg1` and `arg2` where both optional and you only wanted to pass in `arg2`?

Comment: Can we use different variable names other than `arg1`? Like `isFullDate`. I am just asking because every example uses this.

Comment: `'arg1'` and `'arg2'` are just string literals passed as additional parameters to the pipe. You can use any value or reference that is available at that scope (the current component instance)

Comment: @freethebees you got to pass null

Comment: transform method doesn't support array args good point @Gunter

Answer (score 13):

I use Pipes in Angular 2+ to filter arrays of objects. The following takes multiple filter arguments but you can send just one if that suits your needs. Here is a [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvd83e). It will find the keys you want to filter by and then filters by the value you supply. It's actually quite simple, if it sounds complicated it's not, check out the [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvd83e).

**Here is the Pipe being called in an *ngFor directive,**

```
<div *ngFor='let item of items | filtermulti: [{title:"mr"},{last:"jacobs"}]' >
  Hello {{item.first}} !
</div>
```

**Here is the Pipe,**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filtermulti'
})
export class FiltermultiPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(myobjects: Array<object>, args?: Array<object>): any {
    if (args && Array.isArray(myobjects)) {
      // copy all objects of original array into new array of objects
      var returnobjects = myobjects;
      // args are the compare oprators provided in the *ngFor directive
      args.forEach(function (filterobj) {
        let filterkey = Object.keys(filterobj)[0];
        let filtervalue = filterobj[filterkey];
        myobjects.forEach(function (objectToFilter) {
          if (objectToFilter[filterkey] != filtervalue && filtervalue != "") {
            // object didn't match a filter value so remove it from array via filter
            returnobjects = returnobjects.filter(obj => obj !== objectToFilter);
          }
        })
      });
      // return new array of objects to *ngFor directive
      return returnobjects;
    }
  }
}
```

**And here is the Component containing the object to filter,**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FiltermultiPipe } from './pipes/filtermulti.pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  items = [{ title: "mr", first: "john", last: "jones" }
   ,{ title: "mr", first: "adrian", last: "jacobs" }
   ,{ title: "mr", first: "lou", last: "jones" }
   ,{ title: "ms", first: "linda", last: "hamilton" }
  ];
}
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvd83e)

[GitHub Example: Fork a working copy of this example here](https://github.com/beyondJohn/angular5pipefiltermultidynamic)

***Please note** that in an answer provided by Gunter, Gunter states that arrays are no longer used as filter interfaces but I searched the link he provides and found nothing speaking to that claim. Also, the StackBlitz example provided shows this code working as intended in Angular 6.1.9. It will work in Angular 2+.

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: There is no point in passing an single array with multiple entries instead of passing multple parameters directly to the pipe.

Comment: The array contains objects. The objects can contain multiple key value pairs used to create dynamic queries where you can look for matching records using column names compared with the column's row values. You wouldn't get this level of dynamic querying passing CSV parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Also, guys, if you get parser error like me, remember that **pipe name should not contain a dash**.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'arrayFilter' }) // I had 'array-filter'
export class ArrayFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    public transform(items: any[], value: string, props: string[]) { ... }
}
```

***Not parsed:***
`*ngFor="let workflow of workflows | ***array-filter***: workflowFilter:['Name']; trackBy: trackWorkflow"`

***Parsed:***
`*ngFor="let workflow of workflows | ***arrayFilter***: workflowFilter:['Name']; trackBy: trackWorkflow"`

Comment: This is an answer to a totally different question.

Answer (score -3):

Extended from : [user3777549](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48968583/6708046)

Multi-value filter on one set of data(reference to title key only)

HTML

```
<div *ngFor='let item of items | filtermulti: [{title:["mr","ms"]},{first:["john"]}]' >
 Hello {{item.first}} !
</div>
```

filterMultiple

```
args.forEach(function (filterobj) {
    console.log(filterobj)
    let filterkey = Object.keys(filterobj)[0];
    let filtervalue = filterobj[filterkey];
    myobjects.forEach(function (objectToFilter) {

      if (!filtervalue.some(x=>x==objectToFilter[filterkey]) && filtervalue != "") {
        // object didn't match a filter value so remove it from array via filter
        returnobjects = returnobjects.filter(obj => obj !== objectToFilter);
      }
    })
  });
```