# Angular 5, Passing table of tags to pipe filter

Tags: arrays, angular, filter, tags, pipe

I'm new in angular so please be lenient :-)
I'm working with angular 5 and I can't find a way to filter array of objects using array of tags.
I'm trying to pass array of tags ty my custom pipe, unfortunately it doesn't work.
My code looks like this:

**Component**

```
*export class StarsComponent implements OnInit {
....
tagFilter: string[];
....
}*
```

**Pipe**

```
*@Pipe({
name: 'filterByTag'
})
export class FilterByPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(items: any[], prop: string, tags: string[]): any {
    console.log('filterByTag items - ', items);
    console.log('filterByTag prop - ', prop);
    console.log('filterByTag tags - ', tags);
    return items;
}*
```

**View**

```
**<div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" *ngFor="let tag of uniqTags"
    (click)="addTagToFilter(tag)" [ngClass]="{'btn-primary': (tagFilter.indexOf(tag) != -1)}">
    {{tag}}
</button>
</div>
<ul class="stars">
<li *ngFor="let starE of allstars | filterByTag: 'tagFilter': tagFilter"> 
....
</li>
```

**

My console looks like this:

```
filterByTag items -  {array of my items} - it's OK
filterByTag prop -  tagFilter - it's OK
filterByTag tags -**it's empty, why?**
```

Is there any way to pass array of string tags to FilterByPipe ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipes take an array that contains all arguments, so you need to call them like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let starE of allstars | filterByTag: args">


 transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
    console.log('filterByTag items - ', items);
    console.log('filterByTag prop - ', args[0]);
    console.log('filterByTag tags - ', args[1]);
    return items;

args = any[];
args[0] = 'tagFilter';
args[1] = tags;
```

Comment: My transform has an array of all items and it's ok. I need an array of tags to perform filtering. How to build args properly?

Comment: Yo need 1 array of arrays. First element it will be array of all items and second the array of tags. transform function cant receive 3 params since beta 16. see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816788/how-do-i-call-an-angular-2-pipe-with-multiple-arguments

Comment: thank, I've changed my code according to your suggestion: <li *ngFor="let starE of allstars | filterByTag: ['tagFilter', tagFilter]">, but still the last item named tagFilter is empty. I expect to have here the array of tags from my Component

Comment: you're wellcome. if my answer help you pls upvote me :)