# Angular, TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined

Tags: angular, sorting, typescript, html-table, pipe

i'm trying to make a sorting function and pipe for a table by following [this link](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1211/angular-2-search-and-sort-with-ngfor-repeater-with-example) and here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8JxX7HVnO6pJ5M3nSfZq?p=preview) of that example. From the example that i'm following the table header should be clickable and do the `sort()` function. My pipe name is `prdSort`. I'm also using [`ngx-pagination`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pagination) but i don't think that the main cause of this error.

```js
//part of service.ts
productList: AngularFireList < any > ;
//end

//component.ts
productList: Product[];

isDesc: boolean = false;
column: string = 'prdName';
records = this.productList
sort(property) {
  this.isDesc = !this.isDesc; //change the direction    
  this.column = property;
  let direction = this.isDesc ? 1 : -1;
};
```

```html
<!-- table header -->
<th (click)="sort('prdName')">Name</th>

<!--table row-->
<tr *ngFor="let product of productList | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 3, currentPage: p } | prdSort: {property: column, direction: direction} ">
```

```js
//pipe.ts

transform(records: any, args ? : any): any {

  return records.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (records !== undefined) {
      if (a[args.property] < b[args.property]) {
        return -1 * args.direction;
      } else if (a[args.property] > b[args.property]) {
        return 1 * args.direction;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    }
    return records;
  });
};
```

I alse already included the pipe file to `app.module.ts`. Please let me know if more snippets are needed.

Comment: Please paste here your error from `console`. Just copy paste please. Looking at your title `sort of undefined` points to that in your pipe `records` is undefined so sort can't be executed.

Comment: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined
    at PrdSortPipe.transform (prd-sort.pipe.ts:13)
    at checkAndUpdatePureExpressionInline (core.js:12899)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13602)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13541)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14413)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14354)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ProductComponent.html:63)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14339)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13508)
    at callViewAction (core.js:13858)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to initialize your productList with an empty array:

```
// component.ts:

productList: Product[] = [];
```

For more security, to prevent calling *array.prototype.sort* on a variable that is undefined instead of an array, you can add the code below in your filter:

```
transform(records: any, args ? : any): any {
    records = records || [];  // set records to an empty array if undefined
    return records.sort(function(a, b) { ... });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Faly answered this almost perfectly, but your pipe use is invalid in my guess.

From this

```
<tr *ngFor="let product of productList | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 3, currentPage: p } | prdSort: {property: column, direction: direction} ">
```

Change to this

```
<tr *ngFor="let product of productList | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 3, currentPage: p } | prdSort: column : direction ">
```

(Pass arguments changed.)

Also from @Faly

```
transform(records: any, args ? : any): any {
    records = records || [];  // set records to an empty array if undefined
    return records.sort(function(a, b) { ... });
}
```

Explaination: When you look at your error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined at PrdSortPipe.transform` you are trying to use `sort` function on `undefined` due to in my guess badly passed args to pipe. So your pipe gets undefined value on which can't be executed `sort` method. Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36816789/4700863) about multiple args in pipe.

Answer (score 0):

change the prdSort filter to pass only the property name which you want to be sorted.

```
<tr *ngFor="let product of productList |  prdSort: 'prdName' ">
```

You can also include pagination too in the same line