# Disable a button in angular depending on value of property of object inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have an array of object:

```
keyDisabledArray=[
  {'a':false},
  {'b':true}
]
```

and some buttons

```
<button class="key" (click)="keyPressed('a')" id="a">A</button>
<button class="key" (click)="keyPressed('b')" id="b">B</button>
```

that must be disabled according to the content of keyDisabledArray. In this case, button 'b' must be disabled and 'a' enabled. I'm trying to use [disabled] but I'm not sure how to access the correct value in the array of objects.

EDIT: I found some ways to access the value, but all were asynchronous or demanding a full loop on the array to find the correct element, and in both cases, I see problems: how angular deal with asynchronous code in front end (?) and if it is possible to avoid a full loop on the array for every button.

Comment: Have you looked at `async` pipe?

Comment: no, what's that?

Comment: Is this angular 1?

Comment: Truly it's Ionic 2 and so Angular 2

Comment: No. (click) is only available for Angular 2 not AngularJS. Though he said <ng-disabled, which is AngularJS. I think he meant [disabled]

Comment: Oh, my fault, editing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a pipe to extra the correct value.

**Edit**: see how to here to create a pipe which accepts multiple arguments [How do I call an Angular 2 pipe with multiple arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816788/how-do-i-call-an-angular-2-pipe-with-multiple-arguments/36816789)

**Edit #2**: here is a sample piece of code (not tested)

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({
  name: 'isDisabled'
})
export class IsDisabledPipe implements PipeTransform
{

  transform(array: any, key: string): any
  {

    let val = array.find(v => v.hasOwnProperty(key));
    return val? val[key] : false;

  }

}
```

you can then use it like

```
 <button class="key" [disabled]="keyDisabledArray | isDisabled:'a'" (click)="keyPressed('a')" id="a">A</button>
```

Otherwise, why don't you convert your array to a json object?

```
keyDisabledArray=
{
  'a':false,
  'b':true
};
```

then, accessing the value will be easier

```
<button class="key" [disabled]="keyDisabledArray['a']" (click)="keyPressed('a')" id="a">A</button>
```

Comment: Yea, I was deliberately trying to complicate things to understand if it is possible :D Thank you very much anyway! May I ask some hint about pipes just to know how to google it to deepen into this argument?

Comment: I provided a SO link, hope this helps

Comment: I added a sample (not tested though)

Comment: You're my personal hero