# Angular - Custom pipe not working?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pipe

I am attempting to create a custom pipe that will replace one character with another (use case: replacing hyphenated words with space separated words), but I cannot seem to get it working after following online guides and the Angular docs.

**[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-pipe-replacement)**

**pipe.ts**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'replace'
})
export class ReplacePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string, replace: string, withThis: string): any {
    return value.replace(replace, withThis);
  }

}
```

**html usage**

```
<!-- hyphenate = 'some-hyphenated-string' -->

<div>{{hyphenated | replace: {replace: '-', withThis: ' '} }}</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call an Angular 2 pipe with multiple arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816788/how-do-i-call-an-angular-2-pipe-with-multiple-arguments)

Comment: is there a reason for not just using the `replace` method inline with the html?  `{{hyphenated.replace('-', ' ')}}`

Comment: @jtate That would reevaluate the replacement in every change detection cycle. (pure) pipes cache the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) You're not calling your custom pipe correctly:**

Instead of:

```
<div>{{hyphenated | replace: {replace: '-', withThis: ' '} }}</div>
```

Use:

```
<div>{{hyphenated | replace: '-': ' '}}</div>
```

---

**2) Your `replace` usage only replaces the first occurrence in the string:**

Instead of:

```
return value.replace(replace, withThis);
```

Use:

```
return value.replace(new RegExp(replace, 'g'), withThis);
```

[Updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-pipe-replacement-isvms6)

Comment: Thank you for the pointers :-) I knew I was going wrong somewhere!

Comment: @physicsboy Please consider accepting the answer if it indeed answered your question.

Comment: I had to wait for the time limit :P