# Angular 4 Filter Search Custom Pipe for selected columns

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I have created a custom pipe for filtering table data.Now I wanted to add a dropdown that contain the table column, on selecting particular column it will able to search by that column.
Any help on this part is appreciated.

code as below :

**home.component.html**

```
<select id="Select1" [(ngModel)]="selected">
      <option>EmpID</option>
      <option>EmpName</option>
      <option>Age</option>
      <option>Address1</option>
      <option>Address2</option>
    </select>

<input type="text"  placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="query">


<table *ngIf="employee">
    <tr>
        <th>EmpID</th>
            <th>EmpName</th>
                <th>EmpAge</th>
                <th>Address1</th>
                <th>Address2</th>
                <th>Change Detail</th>
                <th>Add Detail</th>

    </tr>

    <tr *ngFor="let employe of employee | search:query |   paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }" >
                <td>{{employe.EmpID}}</td>
                <td>{{employe.EmpName}}</td>
                <td>{{employe.Age}}</td>
                <td>{{employe.Address1}}</td>
                <td>{{employe.Address2}}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="open(employe);">Edit</button></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="add();">Add</button></td>


    </tr>


</table>
```

**Search.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

    if(!value)return null;
    if(!args)return value;

    args = args.toLowerCase();

    return value.filter(function(item){


       return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().includes(args);

    });

}
```

**home.component.ts**

```
employee: any [] = [{
    "EmpID": "1",
    "EmpName": "mukesh12",
    "Age": "182",
    "Address1": "Streptopelia",
    "Address2": "Streptopelia hghg"
},
{
    "EmpID": "2",
    "EmpName": "Rakesh",
    "Age": "1821",
    "Address1": "Streptopelia",
    "Address2": "Streptopelia hghg"
},
{
    "EmpID": "3",
    "EmpName": "abhishek",
    "Age": "184",
    "Address1": "Streptopelia",
    "Address2": "Streptopelia hghg"
},

{
    "EmpID": "4",
    "EmpName": "rawt",
    "Age": "186",
    "Address1": "ktreptopelia",
    "Address2": "Streptopelia hghg"
},

{
    "EmpID": "5",
    "EmpName": "boy",
    "Age": "11",
    "Address1": "Vtgdreptopelia",
    "Address2": "Ttrnneptopelia hghg"
},

{
    "EmpID": "6",
    "EmpName": "himanshu",
    "Age": "28",
    "Address1": "MStreptopelia",
    "Address2": "Streptopelia hghg"
},

{
    "EmpID": "7",
    "EmpName": "katat",
    "Age": "18",
    "Address1": "Streptopelia",
    "Address2": "Streptopelia hghg"
},

{
    "EmpID": "8",
    "EmpName": "gd",
    "Age": "18",
    "Address1": "Streptopelia",
    "Address2": "Streptopelia hghg"
},

{
    "EmpID": "9",
    "EmpName": "tyss",
    "Age": "18",
    "Address1": "Streptopelia",
    "Address2": "Streptopelia hghg"
},


{
    "EmpID": "10",
    "EmpName": "mukesh",
    "Age": "18",
    "Address1": "Streptopelia",
    "Address2": "Streptopelia hghg"
},

{
    "EmpID": "11",
    "EmpName": "mukesh",
    "Age": "18",
    "Address1": "Streptopelia",
    "Address2": "Streptopelia hghg"
},


{
    "EmpID": "12",
    "EmpName": "lopa",
    "Age": "18",
    "Address1": "Streptopelia",
    "Address2": "Streptopelia hghg"
},

{
    "EmpID": "13",
    "EmpName": "todo",
    "Age": "18",
    "Address1": "Streptopelia",
    "Address2": "Streptopelia hghg"
},

{
    "EmpID": "14",
    "EmpName": "mukesh",
    "Age": "16",
    "Address1": "Streptopelia",
    "Address2": "Streptopelia hghg"
},

{
    "EmpID": "15",
    "EmpName": "mukesh",
    "Age": "38",
    "Address1": "Streptopelia",
    "Address2": "Streptopelia hghg"
},

{
    "EmpID": "16",
    "EmpName": "mukesh",
    "Age": "18",
    "Address1": "Streptopelia",
    "Address2": "Streptopelia hghg"
},

{
    "EmpID": "17",
    "EmpName": "see",
    "Age": "08",
    "Address1": "Streptopelia",
    "Address2": "Streptopelia hghg"
},

{
    "EmpID": "18",
    "EmpName": "hmmm",
    "Age": "18",
    "Address1": "Streptopelia",
    "Address2": "Streptopelia hghg"
},

{
    "EmpID": "19",
    "EmpName": "mukesh",
    "Age": "28",
    "Address1": "Streptopelia",
    "Address2": "Streptopelia hghg"
},

{
    "EmpID": "20",
    "EmpName": "tuta",
    "Age": "68",
    "Address1": "Streptopelia",
    "Address2": "Streptopelia hghg"
}];
```

If EmpID is selected then it will search according to Empid in search field, if EmpName is selected  then it will search according to EmpName and so on........

Comment: If EmpID is selected then it will search according to Empid in search field, if EmpName is selected then it will search according to EmpName and so on........

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I wanted to add a dropdown that contain the table column, on selecting particular column it will able to search by that column

Comment: pass multiple argument into your pipe - `searchString`, `columnName` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816788/how-do-i-call-an-angular-2-pipe-with-multiple-arguments

Comment: can u do changes in my code actually im new to this. In search pipe and in templet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another parameter your pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({ name: 'search' })
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, q?: any,colName: any="EmpName"): any {
        if(!value) return null;
        if(!q) return value;
        q = q.toLowerCase();
        return value.filter((item)=> {
            return item[colName].toLowerCase().includes(q);
        });
    }
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let employe of employee | search:query:selected |   paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }" >
```

Comment: If i'm not selecting any column and create a option select in my templet like <option>select</option>. Then it should search normally but when i select column then it search like that  ????

Comment: any help on this will be great

Comment: Put an `if` checking in the `transform` function to check for 'select'.

Comment: if(!colName)
    {

      return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().includes(q);
     
    }

    else
    {
      return item[colName].toLowerCase().includes(q);
    }

Comment: if you add `<option>select</option>` in your select dropdown, then 'select' would be passed as the `colName` to the pipe. So add the `if(colName==='select'){//whatever you want to do} else { return item[colName].toLowerCase().includes(q); }`

Comment: if(colName==='Select')
    {

        return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().includes(q);
     
    }
  

    else
    {
      
      return item[colName].toLowerCase().includes(q);

    }

Comment: if 'select' is selected from dropdown then what do you want to filter it with?

Comment: import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({ name: 'search' })
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, q?: any,colName: any="EmpName"): any {
    if(!value) return null;
    if(!q) return value;
    q = q.toLowerCase();
    return value.filter((item)=> {
      if(colName.toLowerCase()==='select')
      return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().includes(q);
      else
      return item[colName].toLowerCase().includes(q);
    });
  }
}