# angular 6 pipe with multiple arguements html

Tags: javascript, angular

i have the following pipe:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'isInPast'
})
export class IsInPastPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(date: Date, time: any) {
        let today = new Date();
        if (date < today) {

            return 'inPast';
        }
        return '';
    }

}
```

This takes two parameters.

Now i wish to send those in my html but i don't know how. i have tried:

```
 [ngClass]="isInPast:row.day:task.time"
```

i have also tried:

```
 [ngClass]="row.day task.time | isInPast:row.day:task.time"
```

Can anyone tell me how i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to toggle the `inPast` class based on date, implement it like this:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'isInPast'
})
export class IsInPastPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(date: Date, time: any) {
        let today = new Date();
        if (date < today) {

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Then apply it like this

```
 [ngClass]="{'inPast' : row.day | isInPast:task.time }"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'isInPast'
})
export class IsInPastPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(date: Date, time: any) {
        // I don't know what type is at time, let's assume it is Date type.
        let today = time || new Date();
        if (date < today) {
            return 'inPast';
        }
        return '';
    }

}
```

```html
[ngClass]="row.day | isInPast: task.time"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ yourData | isInPast: 'arg1':'arg2':'arg3'... }}
```

[How do I call an Angular 2 pipe with multiple arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816788/how-do-i-call-an-angular-2-pipe-with-multiple-arguments)

Comment: the args here are not strings and the your data doesnt really make sense?