# Filter array of years based on persons age

Tags: angular, typescript

in my project I have an array of years which I want to filter based on person's age, Max age is 65 years, so for example if a person is 61 years old in **years** array will be only 3 and 4.
How can i achieve that?
here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-sfiw23?file=app/app.component.ts)

**.html**

```
      <input
        matInput
        formControlName="birthDate"
        type="text"
        class="form-control age"
        placeholder="ex: 25"
        required/>

 <carousel
    #myCarousel
    height="100%"
    width="120"
    cellsToShow="1"
    overflowCellsLimit="3"
    id="age" >
    <div class="carousel-cell" *ngFor="let year of years">
      {{ year.year }}Years
    </div>
  </carousel>
```

**.ts**

```
  years = [
    {
      year: 3,
      value: 3,
    },
    {
      year: 4,
      value: 4,
    },
  
  ];

  next() {
    this.personAge = (this.formGroup.get('formArray') as FormArray)
      .at(0)
      .get('birthDate').value;
    console.log(this.personAge);
    this.period = this.myCarousel.slideCounter + 3;
    console.log(this.period);
  }
```

Comment: Sorry - what does 3 and 4 have to do with an age of 61…?

Comment: oh sry for bad explaining, i meant if max age is 65 years in project and person is 61 years old, he cant choose 5 years, bcuz 61 + 5 = 66, so he can choose 3years and 4 years. did i explained it good? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to filter the data.

Something along the lines of this should work:

```
const years = [{year: 3, value: 3}, {year: 4, value: 4}, {year: 5, value: 5}, {year: 6, value: 6}, {year: 7, value: 7}];
const age = 60;
const result = years.filter(year => year.value + age <= 65); 
// result: [{year: 3, value: 3}, {year: 4, value: 4}, {year: 5, value: 5}]
```

If you want to do it directly on the template you could use a [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) to filter it.

UPDATE:

The pipe code you have is almost correct, you missed two things.

- Since the pipe has multiple inputs you need to specify the inputs after the first one. [How do I call an Angular 2 pipe with multiple arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816788/how-do-i-call-an-angular-2-pipe-with-multiple-arguments)
- I used const age in my example since it was just that. You should use **this.age** as reference to the component variable, not a function variable, so you can send it to the pipe.

Here is how the pipe could be coded:

`age-filter.pipe.ts`

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'ageFilter',
})
export class AgeFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(
    years: { year: number; value: number }[],
    age: number
  ): { year: number; value: number }[] {
    return years.filter((year) => year.value + age <= 65);
  }
}
```

`component.html`

```html
<div class="carousel-cell" *ngFor="let year of years | ageFilter: age">
    {{ year.year }}Years
</div>
```

Also, for future questions, please remember this: [How much research effort is expected of stack overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Posting a new question should be your last resort.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer and sorry for my question, i am new to this!
Also, i am trying to do impelemnt filtered data in my html with pipes as you said but it doesnt work, what am i doing wrong? i updated my stackblitz

Comment: Hi @GalathyniusAelin, do not worry, just take it into account before posting future questions. 
I edited the answer with how to implement the pipe, you almost got it, you missed two things. Check the answer and let me know if I need to improve it further.

Comment: hey, thank u again. updated stackblitz, i implemented your pipe in my code it works perfect with the div, but in my carousel it doesnt show data, is it because the carousel i am using?

Comment: @GalathyniusAelin It seems the carousel is having some issues with the dynamic data changes so the issue lies with the component not the filtering method. I took a look at their [GitHub](https://github.com/ivylaboratory/angular-carousel) and found [this answer](https://github.com/ivylaboratory/angular-carousel/issues/52). It seems that you need to refresh/re-render the component every time the data changes.

Comment: thank you so much again! i will try to do re-renderring!