# How to use Multiple Params in Angular 12 Pipes?

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, angular12

I am trying to pass multiple parameter in angular 12 pipes but unfortunately its giving below error

```
Error: src/app/app.component.html:3:32 - error TS2339: Property 'xyz' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
```

below is my ts code

```
  transform(currency: any, value: any, args: any, ): unknown {
    
    return "Your value is " + value + "your x value is" + args + "and your curr value is" + currency;
  }
```

my html code is

```
<h1>{{20 | usdPkr: abc : def : xyz }}</h1>
```

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816788/how-do-i-call-an-angular-2-pipe-with-multiple-arguments

Comment: Error says you have no `xyz` property in your component, but want use it in pipe

Comment: `xyz` should be a variable in your .ts if you want pass a "literal" enclosed by single quotes, e.g. `{{20|usdPrk:abc:def:'xyx'}`